# 500 charge limit on wireless charger for Nexus 4 / 5 (QI)

Tags: battery, charging, nexus-5, wireless-charging

I recently bought a QI compatible charger for my Nexus 5. On the box it states, that the **"wireless charges up to 500 times"**.

- I don't understand why the charger is only able to charge my phone 500 times.
- What happens to the charger so that it does not work anymore? Can someone explain that?

Thanks for you help.

It is exactly this device:
[QI charger from ravpower](http://www.ravpower.com/ravpowerr-qi-enabled-single-position-wireless-charger-charging-pad-white-us-version.html)

**Edit 2:** Looking at the website of the maker, it seems that they sell a mobile power bank as well. Perhaps they use the same packaging for the mobile power bank wireless charger and the wireless charger without battery.

**Edit 3:** I found the packaging on the internet.

[Picture of the box](http://v-i-t-t-i.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ravpower-qi-wireless-charger-im-kurztest-3.jpg)

Comment: This may be describing the battery, not the charger. 500 charge/discharge cycles is a pretty normal spec for a cell phone battery. Do you think you could [edit] your question with the exact wording printed on the packaging? (I'm curious about what it says)

Comment: I would imagine it is the battery. Wireless charging is pretty brutal on some mobile batteries. I'd tend to stick with the 'wired' kind. Mind you both hav a wire, but the one you plug in to the wall and the phone, not the one you plug into the wall and rest the phone on! (Wireless charging is a silly name IMHO)